# Appending a line in sed doesn't work even with escape characters

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use Bash scripts in Vagrant to automate the setup of an ELK stack. One of the nginx configuration files requires the right amount of indentation.

I tried:

```
sudo sed -i '28 a \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

which should append a line that is 8 spaces away from the margin and right where I need it but when I check the configuration file, the spaces aren't added in.

I have successfully used:

```
sudo sed -i '73 a \ \ \ \ bika.lims' /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/buildout.cfg
```

in a different project before, which added the correct number of spaces.
Am I doing something wrong this time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first command works for me just fine. Also without escaping the spaces, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get indentation from line 28 and use it when you added new line.

For example, in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default in line 28 you have
something like this:

```
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
```

Then you can do this:

```
sudo sed -i 's,^\([[:space:]]*\).*include snippets/snakeoil.conf.*,&\n\1auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users,' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

1. In substitute command `s/regexp/replacement/` used comma as separator `s,regexp,replacement,`. It's help do not quote `/` inside regexp.
2. `^\([[:space:]]*\).*include snippets/snakeoil.conf.*` regexp to match line with `# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;`

   2.1 `^\([[:space:]]*\)` matching sub-expressions group`\(\)`. Match all spaces from beginning of the line. Now it can be refer with special escapes `\1` (see step 3.3).
3. `&\n\1auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users` this what will be replaced.

   3.1 `&` -  special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched. So it's just preserving old line
   `# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;` on place.

   3.2 `\n` - new line

   3.3 `\1` - special escapes `\1` to refer to the sub-expressions from step 2.1

   3.4 `auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users` - text what need to be added